# How to connect PhoneGap App to MySql Database on the server?

Tags: cordova

I am trying to build a transit mobile application that has data stored in MySql DB on the server. Since my application is just going to connect to the MySql db and fire query/get the data and show it to the user . I was planning to create it using PhoneGap but i don't understand how will i connect to the MySql DB does phonegap only allow local data storage using SqlLite ? Can someone brief me on the architecture i should take into consideration for building this transit app.

Answer (score 5):

You can use AJAX in your PhoneGap app to get data from your MySQL DB, you will need a script on your server to handle these calls. CGI/ PHP/ Ruby/ NodeJS etc... all of these will fit the job description.

Comment: Thanks @James Wong ... one more question the script file for eg a PHP will be stored on my Webserver right not in my PhoneGapp application ? Not sure on that.

Comment: Yes exactly, PHP file on your webserver whose purpose is to connect to your MySQL DB and echo the data into a JSON string. From your PhoneGap app, you can create an HTML page and use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to process the JSON string. It sounds daunting but give it a try :) there are plenty of resources on the internet involving AJAX calls. Feel free to open a new question if you encounter any trouble along the way.

Comment: can you please look at this thread and help me with that  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124308/how-to-make-a-connection-to-php-file-on-a-webserver-using-phonegapandriod-app

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to get json data from your own website.
For example, this code is used to get the user's username by his id.
JS on your phonegap app:

```
function getUsername(){
    var id = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.example.com/json_read?id=" + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.username);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP on your website:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
$result = $sql->fetch_assoc();
$object->username = $result['username'];
$json = json_encode($object);

echo $json;
?>
```

Make sure you are only using it on phonegap so no one can see your source code and play with your database :)