# Is there any datatable for mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, datatables

I am using bootstrap for designing the mobile app. Is there any datatable available for it. Actually nprmal datatable using ajax is working fine in the desktop but not in the mobile (ie. after i put it in the PG Build)
...any suggestions?

Comment: database is database, but what i can see is you are confuse about using cordova... you know you have to have a API for using it properly and get all context via ajax, since cordova only support html files and not php files

Comment: This question could be a duplicate of [How to connect PhoneGap App to MySql Database on the server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977719/how-to-connect-phonegap-app-to-mysql-database-on-the-server/21978394#21978394)