# Accessing external Database from MySQL in HTML Jquery Mobile Application(Phonegap)

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am intending to use a Database (already created) from MySQL to be used in HTML JQuery Mobile Application.
i.e fetch the values from the Database and display it on the client end.
Something for like an offline Storage say.

What procedure should be followed , i mean can we follow the same procedure as in Android .. i.e importing the .sql file and placeing it in assests and then accesing the same.
What is the functionality with Cross Platform.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is to create a PHP file that handles the Mysql queries and Json output the results. On your HTLM side you use Ajax ($.post()) in you JS scripts to post to the PHP file to get the results.

Comment: is there any possibilty of executing the same without PHP

Comment: Cordova just creates a webview with some added functionality and JQM is web based so i would have thought you need some server side script to handle databases. A native app works a bit different as you mentioned you add mysql functionality to the App to connect and request data ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977719/how-to-connect-phonegap-app-to-mysql-database-on-the-server

Comment: for cordova storage check this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage